# How do I align a checkbox and edittext field side by side in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

I am trying to make a checkbox and an `edittext` field side by side inside my `LinearLayout`. This is my code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_dialog"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    <com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox
        android:id="@+id/report_bill_period"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Incorrect bill period"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
    </com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox>

    <com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox
        android:id="@+id/report_bill_amount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Incorrect bill amount"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
    </com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox
            android:id="@+id/anything_else"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
        </com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:hint="Anything else?"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:lines="10"
                android:maxLines="10" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the output that I get:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXSa2.png)

---

As you can see in the screenshot, the third checkbox isn't aligned properly with the first two checkboxes. How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set linear layout gravity to center

```
<LinearLayout  
  android:layout_width="match_parent"        
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:gravity="center">
  <!-- checkbox and textfield code -->
</LinearLayout>
```

You can also use a relative layout

Or you can also wrap checkbox and textfield inside a constraint layout and constraint the children in such a way that they become vertically centered

Answer (score 0):

Add `minWidth` and `minHeight` for Checkbox. It will remove the default padding.

```
android:minWidth="0dp"
android:minHeight="0dp"
```